# Possible for a Ruby function to detect number of return values requested?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, a function can return multiple* values.  Is it possible for a Ruby function to determine how many return values its invoking code is expecting?

For instance:

```
a = f()                  # caller expects one return value
a, b = f()               # caller expects two return values
a, b, c = f()            # caller expects three return values
```

If we let `r` be the number of expected return values, is it possible to write a function `f` such that it can find `r`?

Specifically, how could we change the definition of `rcount`, below, such that is passes the following tests:

```
a, b = rcount()
puts "#{a},#{b}"           # FAIL, DESIRED: "2,1"      ACTUAL: "1,"
a, b, c = rcount()
puts "#{a},#{b},#{c}"      # FAIL, DESIRED: "3,2,1"    ACTUAL: "1,,"
a, b, c, d = rcount()
puts "#{a},#{b},#{c},#{d}" # FAIL, DESIRED: "4,3,2,1"  ACTUAL: "1,,,"
```

Where `rcount` is defined like this:

```
def rcount()
  ret = []
  r = nil                  # <== Q. IS IT POSSIBLE TO GET r PROGRAMMATICALLY?
  r ||= 1
  last = r - 1
  (0..last).each do |i|
    ret[i] = r - i
  end
  ret
end
```

*Actually multiple return values is syntactic sugar, the real return value is a single array.  All Ruby functions return exactly one value.

Comment: Why are you using this function `a,b,c = rcount(3)` if You could use just: `a,b,c = (1..3).to_a`

Comment: @gustavotkg, `rcount` is meant to be a simple function to demonstrate my question.  It's not necessarily meant to be useful.  I ask the question out of curiosity and to improve my understanding of Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The Ruby environment doesn't give you that information. You could use an exception and ParseTree to find out what the calling code looks like, but that is overkill :)

Comment: I like the `ParseTree` suggestion, although I agree it's overkill.

Answer (score 8):

Ruby functions have always exactly one return value. What you use is a rather nifty feature of ruby which allows to destructure arrays using the comma operator. This works similar to the splat (asterisk) operator which can be used as a reverse operator.

Consider this example

```
def rcount(number)
  # this returns an array containing the 1 till number
  (1..number).to_a
end

array = rcount(3)
# array is set to [1, 2, 3]

a, b, c = rcount(3)
# a is set to 1
# b is set to 2
# c is set to 3

x, y = rcount(3)
# x is set to 1
# y is set to 2
# the last value is thrown away

r, t, z = rcount(2)
# r is set to 1
# t is set to 2
# z is set to nil
```

So basically, there is no need to check the number or elements in a returned array, at least for syntactic correctness. If you need to rely on the fact that you have always the exact matching number of array elements, you should check that using tests.

Just remember, that you are actually dealing with array here. And as the destructuring of the array is done after the function return the array, there is no way for it to know what is done with the value afterwards. This is completely independent from function calling.

As a final advice, if you actually would require something like this in a piece of production software, you should seriously reconsider your design as something like this introduces heavy coupling of functions. Duck typing is a gift. Use it generously.

Comment: Very good answer. There a little tipo in the rcount(3) example. y is set to 2 and 3 is thrown away ;)

Comment: @Holger, Great explanation of how multiple return values work.  Unfortunately that doesn't really answer the question: is it possible to detect the number of "return values" requested.  The point is to write `rcount` such that it can be called with NO arguments.  I'll edit my question to make this more clear.

Comment: @jwfearn: As I said in my second last paragraph, it is not possible. The `rcount` function itself has absolutely no knowledge about how its returned values are used. All that happens after the function ceased control over things. You could only try implementation specific tools like `ParseTree` for MRI to have a look at the call stack. But I doubt that it's possible even then. It's just not not how Ruby works. E.g. what would happen if you take the array as is and dissect it later? You would need to detect that too.

Comment: @jwfearn: Because, well, you don't "request" multiple values. You get exactly one return value which might happen to be an array. What happens after that is nothing a function can control. The only thing you could use is to pass a block for callbacks. You can then ask that block how many arguments it can accept using `arity`. You could then perform the work on the results in that block. This technique is called dependency injection and can actually be rather useful.

Comment: @Holger, Thanks again for your insights.  Obviously at *some* time (certainly after the function call, perhaps before) the Ruby interpreter knows how many variables are on the left hand side of the expression `a, b, c = rcount()` but apparently that information is not currently exposed by an API.  Even if such an API existed, I agree that one should seriously consider its appropriateness as a solution (as one would any solution.)  I'm just trying to discover Ruby's inner secrets.  Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Use caller to get the file and line number.
You can then read the line of code to see how the function is called:

```
def get_line(f,n)
  File.open(f,'r') do |fh|
    i = 0
    fh.each_line do |ln|
      i+=1
      return ln if i==n
    end
  end
end

def f()
  if caller.first=~/([^:]+):(\d+)/
    f,n = $1,$2.to_i
    line = get_line(f,n)
    case line
    when /\w+,\s*\w+\s*=\s*f\(/
      return [2, 3]
    when /=\s*f\(/
      return 1
    else
       puts 0
     end
  end
end

f()
a = f()
puts "a = #{a}"
b,c = f()
puts "b,c = #{b},#{c}"
```

The output is:

```
0
a = 1
b,c = 2,3
```

But, yeah...
This context is not part of the Ruby language:

Comment: Please don't do this. Ever. This is *incredibly* brittle, doesn't work with meta-programming and is slow as hell.